# Spawn new controller or use existing? Titanium SDK

Tags: javascript, android, model-view-controller, titanium

In an effort to learn more about MVC and Titanium SDK, I have started to develop a small Android app from scratch (not using Alloy).
Each controller is responsible for constructing the corresponding view and model data.

When a button is pressed to display another screen, how do I determine if a controller(and view) for the requested screen already exists? If it already exists I would like to display it, otherwise initialize a new controller.

```
var LoginController = function() {

function setEventListeners ( myWindow ) {
    myWindow.butSettings.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // When pressed, this should check if there is already
        // an existing "SettingsController", if not then spawn
        // a new one via "myParent.Settings = new SettingsController"
        alert("test");
    });

}

//var model = new LoginModel();
var view = new LoginView.init;
setEventListeners(view);

return view;
};

var myParent = {}; // parent object
myParent.Login = new LoginController;
myParent.Login.open();
```

Comment: I think in this case you could just say `if(!myParent.Settings) { //create controller } else { //use myParent.Settings }`.

Comment: Save the screen you create to a global variable and null it when you want to destroy it.  Check the global variable to see if it is null, otherwise create it.